Can we apply Fourier transform on non stationary data?

Hi, I'm trying to predict US inflation rate. The unit is in percentage change from a year ago. Would it be possible to use Fourier transform on the independent data to create a new feature, knowing that it's non stationary? If possible can I also get more reference? I'm new to time series, but did a course on forecasting.

You can compute anything you want, including the FT.  The better question to ponder is whether that will be useful or meaningful to you.  For predicting any inflation rate it's likely a bad procedure because inflation is not going to exhibit predictable perfect cyclic behavior, not even approximately.  (That's an economic opinion, not a statistical one.)

this is what I thought also, glad my intuition wasn't that off. Thanks!
